# How to change a scene in project from another project

Tags: java, javafx, actionlistener

I have two separate java projects and I want to make something that w a button is clicked in the first project, the scene in project two changes.
The application is something that have the same idea of Uber so when the confirm button is clicked in the customer application, the scene in the employee app changes to show the location of the customer

Comment: Due to a [moderator/volunteer strike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderator-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-and?r=Saves_AllUserSaves) I will not be performing any content curation on this question.

Comment: This is too broad a question for stack overflow. You need to decide how the two applications are going to communicate (peer-to-peer/central server, protocol, etc.). Then you need to design each application to listen for incoming messages. When a message is received, perform an action based on the content/type of the message. Part of that action, or at least a consequence of that action, should be an update to the UI. All this will involve multithreading. But remember: The live scene graph of a JavaFX application _must_ only be interacted with on the _JavaFX Application Thread_.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.